# php: chars from String without conversion

Tags: php, character-encoding

i try to decode a string with php. It was coded bevore with vba on another machine. The Strings will come from a database. But for the first time a hardcoded String, to find the problems. The Teststring is "¦ÞµºÎ× hg". With VBA i get the following result when exploding to chars an get the Ascii Values:

```html
¦ÞµºÎ× hg <- the String

9 <- length of the String

1:¦:166  <- first Char = "¦", Ascii Code 166
2:Þ:222  <- second Char = "Þ", Ascii Code 222
3:µ:181  and so on
4:º:186
5:Î:206
6:×:215
7: :160
8:h:104
9:g:103
```

when Trying the same with php maybe php thinks this is UTF8 coded or anything else and gives me wrong chars:

```html
"¦ÞµºÎ× hg" <- Input String

16 <- length 16???

b"""       <- i dindn't know from where this is?!
\n
1:¦:166\n  <- first Char = "¦", Ascii Code 166, correct!
2:Ã:195\n  <- second Char = "Ã", Ascii Code 195, WTF?
3:ž:158\n
4:Â:194\n
5:µ:181\n
6:Â:194\n
7:º:186\n
8:Ã:195\n
9:Ž:142\n
10:Ã:195\n
11:—:151\n
"""

""
```

I've tried different ways to get the chars out of the String and i've tried different things with detect_encoding and iconv, but the result stays always the same:

```html
$strToDecode = "¦ÞµºÎ× hg"
$lenEnc = mb_strlen($strToDecode, 'ASCII');

 $r = "";
 $asci = 0;
 $char = "";
 $rTest = "\n";
 for($i=1; $i <= $lenEnc-5; $i++) {
  //$r = Right($strToDecode, $lenEnc - $i );
  //$r = mb_substr($strToDecode, $i, 1, "ASCII");  
  $r = $strToDecode[$i];  
  $asci = ord($r);
  $rTest .= $i . ":" . $r . ":" . $asci . "\n";
  $strResult .= $char;
 }  

dd($strToDecode, $lenEnc, $rTest, $strResult);
```

What can i do, to get the real chars without changing them?

Many thanks for every tip :)

best Regards.

Comment: String length in PHP means byte count, not number of UTF-8 characters. You should stick to the `mb_*` functions for an equivalent result. See also [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: i use mb_strlen, see 2.nd line !?

Comment: And then... you access bytes instead `$strToDecode[$i];` - furthermore if you ask for `'ASCII'` then using `mb_*` is widely pointless.

Comment: mb_strlen gives me 16 as length for the harcoded String "¦ÞµºÎ× hg" with the len 9. And mb_substr($strToDecode, $i, 1, "ASCII is one of a lot tries but all of them says the second char of "¦ÞµºÎ× hg" is Ã

Comment: i've not all my tries in the code above! But i'va had a lot. I'm not able to get the correct length (9) and the correct second char "Þ" until now.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your string `"¦ÞµºÎ× hg"` is probably stored in multi-bytes in your PHP file (the source file) and you are using the `ASCII` parameter.

If you just removed the `ASCII` parameter(because it's not ASCII) from the mb_* functions your code will work as you expect

```
$strToDecode = "¦ÞµºÎ× hg";
$lenEnc = mb_strlen($strToDecode);// REMOVED 'ASCII'
//var_dump($lenEnc); // its 9 NOW
$r = "";
$vp = 0;
$asci = 0;
$gofi = 0;
$char = "";
$rTest = "\n";
$strResult = "";
for($i=0; $i < $lenEnc; $i++) {
    $r = mb_substr($strToDecode, $i, 1);// REMOVED 'ASCII'
    $asci = ord($r);
    $rTest .= $i . ":" . $r . ":" . $asci . "\n";
    $strResult .= $char;
}
var_dump($rTest);exit;
```

this outputs on my machine

```
string(78) "
0:¦:194
1:Þ:195
2:µ:194
3:º:194
4:Î:195
5:×:195
6: :32
7:h:104
8:g:103
"
```

I have made another test to verify . I changed the source file encoding to ANSI (after making a backup of the file), and your old code works fine with the `ASCII` parameters. change it with your editor to see with yourself.

Comment: mystical. on my machine this didn't work. This was the first Version.

Comment: i've found now, that with $strToDecode = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $strToDecode) at the beginng it works on my machine. Thanks.

Comment: @K.G. you are welcome . also change the source file encoding to ANSI with your editor and check your old code and it will work.

Comment: Shit. With another String, now from the db it didn't work.I get "illegal Character in String from iconv. What i did'nt understand: He Shows the correct string at the beginning. <pre>"¦èÃ²ÈÙ¦«£ŸæÀ³âÔ¢ÆÝu¼»¹ž¬º­à"

53

b"""
\n
1:┬:194\n
2:ª:166\n
3:├:195\n
4:¿:168\n
5:├:195\n
6:â:131\n </pre> When i copy and paste the String at the beginng to my vba code i get the correct encoded String. Why php shows the String like i wan't but doesen't give me the chars, that i see there? :/

Comment: Saving as Ansi i can' find within visual studio code. But at this point i haven't the string hardcoded. now i get it from the db and like my answer below, now i get 80% string corrrect encoded. Changing from iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $strToDecode)  to iconv("ANSI", "ISO-8859-1", $strToDecode) brings no help. Then there is no one correct :/

Answer (score 0):

With $strToDecode = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", $strToDecode);
 i get mostly 80% of the strings encoded now. But in some cases i get
for example  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string, bei ¬ÛÆ¿ÄÚ¦½¢˜žn—åÖ¬Ìß¯ÊÉg[†º¤ÞÛèå«ÆÜ¢§®¾¢Ç¡ËÖÑ¨

mb_detect_encoding($strToDecode, 'auto'); says it's UTF-8 in booth cases.
In the mysql table, the data comes from there is latin 1 - latin1_german1_ci in the settings and i can't change this because the db is used from some more files since years, without this problems. They work with vba and i can't change them all ;)